# Android Development Kit - Changing the values of strings

Tags: java, android, string, casting, adt

I recently started to use the ADT (also I don't know java yet, I'm familiar with C++).

I added a `TextView` which has a string as its text:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" 
    android:text="@string/button_clicked" />

<string name="button_clicked">0</string>
```

(In the file **activity_main.xml** for layout and string.xml for the string)

Now my problem is to change the text in that **TextView**. But I don't want to change it directly, I want to change the string. (this happens due to a `onClick` event of a button)

Up to now I didn't work out how to do that and as well, how to cast the value of an int into that string somehow (I want it to count up / display the value of this integer).

Can you guys help me out? :)

Comment: Use the `setText` method and `String.valueOf`?

Comment: tv.setText(getText(R.string.button_clicked)); some thing like this our u want diffrent

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to set a String as text:

```
myTextView.setText(myString);
```

For integers, use:

```
myTextView.setText(Integer.toString(integer));
```

For string resources, use:

```
myTextView.setText(R.string.my_string_res);
```